# Trying to get property of non-object ErrorException (E_NOTICE)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to isert data in mysql using laravel, while I am getting the error ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object, where is the problem I dont know please help me.

my controller code is PublicationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\publication;
use Auth;

class PublicationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('publications');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        publications::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'title' => request('title'),
            'status' => request('status'),
            'year' => request('research_area')
        ]);
        return 'inserted';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

While model code is given publication.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class publication extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['title','status','year'];
}
```

The code of my route is given.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('education', 'EducationController@index');
Route::post('edu', 'EducationController@store');

Route::get('publications','PublicationController@index');
Route::post('pub','PublicationController@store');
```

The error is given Class ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object please help if any one know where is the problem

Comment: I think `Auth::user()->id` might be the problem. Check to see if `Auth::user()` is null.

Comment: id is the primary key in user table, while it is used as foriegn key in publication table named user_id

Comment: user table containg the data, it is not empty

Comment: Your store method references `publications` and your use statement is `App\publication`

Comment: publication is my model while publications is the name of the table in mysql database

Comment: Right. Take a closer look at the code you posted, specifically the store method in your controller `publications::create`

Answer (score 1):

Consider placing `PublicationController` behind authentication middleware:

```
class PublicationController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    ...
}
```

You can also use route groups:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // your routes
});
```

If `Auth::user()` is null then `Auth::user()->id` will give you the exception you mentioned. Placing the routes or controller behind the middleware should solve this.

**Edit**

This assumes you are using Laravel 5.6 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6. This should work for 5.5 and 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer of my question by just including 'user_id' in my model fillable arry and the above code works properly.

Answer (score 0):

İ think you are not logged in so you get error when you try to get `Auth::user()-id`
Add this contractor to your class i think it should work for you

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```